# Using TASKER to automatically change launcher/theme when launcher/theme is changed by other program

Tags: tasker, huawei, launcher, nova-launcher

I am using a Huawei P9+ running on Android 7 (Nougat) and one of the annoying things with it is from time to time, the theme reverts back to the ugly Huawei Home theme, even though I use Nova Launcher by default.

Right now my strategy is I manually go to Apps -> Default App Settings -> Launcher to change it to Nova Launcher, however from time to time it would revert back again randomly.

I have Tasker installed and I am wondering if there is some way I can configure it so that whenever the launcher is changed to something other than Nova Launcher, it would be able to switch back to Nove Launcher automatically?

Forgot to mention I have Secure Settings (paid version) installed and my phone is rooted (using Super User, there is no proper SuperSu that works on this one yet).